# How to submit input by pressing enter without a form in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to submit an input in React.js by pressing enter without using a form.
It this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Just check if Enter pressed, then call your action.

```
function handleKeyDown(event) {
   if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      // call action
  }
}

<input onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
```